# Webpack handlebars-loader hangs website

Tags: webpack, webpack-plugin

I am trying to load handlebars-loader`enter code here`, but my app hangs. It loads `app.bundle.js` but then not execute any futher scripts. There is no output in console.

```
module.exports = {
     module: {
         loaders: [{
                 exclude: /node_modules/,
                 loader: 'handlebars-loader'
             }, {
                 test: /\.js$/,
                 exclude: /node_modules/,
                 loader: 'babel-loader'
             }]
     }
};
```

When I try to load `handlebars` via plugin:

```
plugins: [
          new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
             handlebars: "handlebars",
             "windows.handlebars": "handlebars"
         })
     ],
```

I have `handlevars` defuned but `webpack` gives the error after compilation:

```
ERROR in ./~/handlebars/lib/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'E:\Dev\Micron\node_modules\handlebars\lib'
 @ ./~/handlebars/lib/index.js 17:11-24
 @ ./src/core/index.js
 @ ./src/app.js
```

How can I laod `handlebars` via webpack?